# How to display the right record

Tags: php, sql, pdo, where-clause

I testing my skills and I am trying to make a forum. Now I have it that it displays the right boards,topics and reactions but now I need it to make it that it only will display the 'omschrijving/subject' by the right topics.

This code will display the right reacties(reactions) by the right topic.

```
$actieftopicid = $topic['id'];
if(isset($actieftopicid)){
                $reacttie = $app->get_reactie($actieftopicid);
                foreach ($reacttie as $reactie) {

                    if (file_exists('assets/images/profielfotos/' . $reactie['klant_id'])) {
                        echo '<li class="time-label">
                            <span class="bg-red">' .$reactie['datum'] .'</span>
                            </li>

                        <li><img class="img-circle reactieafbeelding" src="/assets/images/profielfotos/' . $reactie['klant_id'] . '/' . $reactie['foto'] . '" /><div class="timeline-item reactiewidth">
                                <span class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> ' .$reactie['tijd'] .'</span>  

                                <h3 class="timeline-header"><a href="#">' .$reactie['voornaam'] .' ' .$reactie['achternaam'] .'</a> ...</h3>  

                                <div class="timeline-body">
                                    '.$reactie['reactie']
                                .'</div>
                                <div class="timeline-footer">
                              <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i><a href="#reactie" style="color:black; margin-left: 2px;">Reageer</a></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>'; } else{ echo 'balbal';}
```

The function by that:

```
 public function get_reactie($topicid){
        $this->database->query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(create_time, '%d %M %Y') AS datum, ledenpagina.ledenpagina_id, DATE_FORMAT(create_time, '%H:%i') AS tijd, reacties.*, klanten.foto, topics.omschrijving, topics.topicnaam, klanten.voornaam, klanten.achternaam FROM reacties 
        LEFT JOIN klanten ON klanten.id = reacties.klant_id
        LEFT JOIN topics ON topics.id = reacties.topic_id
        LEFT JOIN ledenpagina ON ledenpagina.ledenpagina_id = reacties.ledenpagina_id
        WHERE ledenpagina.ledenpagina_id=:ledenpagina_id AND reacties.topic_id=:topic_id
        ORDER BY create_time DESC");

        $this->database->bind(":ledenpagina_id", $_SESSION['ledenpagina_id']);
        $this->database->bind(":topic_id", $topicid);

        $reacties = $this->database->resultset();

        return $reacties;

    }
```

I now need some kind of function/php code that will get the omschrijving(subject) by the right topics.

The databases:
[image: topic database]
[image: reactie(reaction) db]

So somehow I need to make it that it will check the topic_id and display the omschrijving(subject) by that topic_id.

Comment: The question is unclear, the language is uncomprehensible, it's not clear what you have tried so far, it's not clear what you need and where it should be found..

Comment: What I want is: some code or some function that will return the subject(called omschrijving in the db) based on the topic_id that is selected. I added the example how I display my reaction to make it clear. @Yuri

Comment: I cannot see that field in the 2 DB pictures you posted..

Comment: Sorry I eddited it @Yuri

Comment: I really don't see the problem in what you want to do.. If you have the `topic_id` it is just a very simple query to the DB

Comment: @Yuri Well if thats the case can you please help me with it, I can't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

You are already fetching it with the query in the `get_reactie()` function, so you can access it in your `foreach` loop with `$reactie['omschrijving']`.

If you want to get it by topic_id, you can make a single query like

```
function getTopicSubject($topic_id){
    $result = $db->query("SELECT omschrijving FROM topics WHERE id = $topic_id;");
    return $result->fetchColumn();
}
```

[FetchColumn](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) will return your value or `FALSE` if missing.

Comment: Its not finding the `$topic_id` , It is not possible to ask for the `$topic_id` if its in a different file? because the functions are in a different file.

Comment: Sure, you have to fill the `$topic_id` according to your needs.. I edit my answer to match your post question